# How to load 3D Model in FireMonkey at run time

Tags: model, 3d, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe4

I could load 3D model by property meshCollection,
just like [Importing a 3D Model in a FireMonkey Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Importing_a_3D_Model_in_a_FireMonkey_Application) .

But it could not load model by `Model3D->LoadFromFile("filepath.obj")`

I try a lot of time, but it still not work!

Is it a bug for Firemonkey XE4?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: The Model don't present on Viewport3D,
and the address of FMeshCollection is NULL.
http://i.imgur.com/lDfvbFU.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Did you connect the module FMX.OBJ.Importers?
Loading doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

for C++ builder you need to include the

```
#include <FMX.OBJ.Importer.hpp>
```

for dae and ese you should look for

```
FMX.DAE.Importer.TDAEModelImporter
FMX.ASE.Importer.TASEModelImporter
```

see also delphi2010.ru/firemonkey-на-практике-5/
for a example in delphi

Comment: #include <FMX.OBJ.Importer.hpp>

Comment: In delphi too!!!
Include FMX.OBJ.Importer or FMX.DAE.Importer or FMX.ASE.Importer